# RadioButtonGroup-formControlName not working with reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

I want to a create a RadioComponent which populates the input and Label.

I want this component to work with ngModel and reactive forms.

So i created a RadioGroup by implementing ControlValueAccessor, and RadioButton Component which populates Input and Label.

I am calling these component from a parent component where I defined FormGroup but  reactive form is not working with this approach.

Can someone please suggest where I am going wrong.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mipzzw

**RadioGroupComponent**

```
import { Component, Input, forwardRef, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { RadioButtonComponent } from '../radio-button/radio-button.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'radio-group',
  templateUrl: './radio-group.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./radio-group.component.css'],
providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => RadioGroupComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ],
})
export class RadioGroupComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  constructor() { }

 private _value: any = null;

    @ContentChildren(forwardRef(() => RadioButtonComponent), { descendants: true })
    radios: QueryList<RadioButtonComponent>;

    _onChange = (value: any) => {
        console.log('onChange=', value);
    }
    _onTouched = () => { };

    writeValue(value: any): void {
        console.log('writeValue=', value);
        this._onChange(value);
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => {}): void {
        this._onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: () => {}): void {
        this._onTouched = fn;
    }

    get value(): any {
        console.log('get value', this._value);
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(val) {  // this value is updated by programmatic changes
        if (val !== undefined && this._value !== val) {
            this._value = val;
            this._onChange(val);
            this._onTouched();
        }
    }
}
```

**RadioComponent**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'radio-button',
    template: `
        <input type="radio"
            (change)="changeValue(value)"
            class="input-control"
            [id]="inputId"
            [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"
            [value]="value"
            [formControlName]="inputName"/>

        <label
            for="{{ inputId }}">
            <span>{{ label | translate }}</span>
        </label>
    `,        
    styleUrls: ['./radio.less']
})

export class RadioComponent {
    @Input() selectedOption: string;
    @Input() inputId: string;
    @Input() value: string;
    @Input() label: string;
    @Input() inputName: string;

    @Output() selectedOptionChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    changeValue(value: any) {
        this.selectedOptionChange.emit(value);
    }                                            
}
```

**Demo Component**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-radio',
    template: `

            <div  [formGroup]="exampleForm">
                <radio-button *ngFor="let option of options"
                    [inputId] = "option.value"
                    [label]="option.display"
                    [value]="option.value"
                    (selectedOptionChange) = "selectedOptionChange($event)"
                    formInputName= "gender"
                    [selectedOption]="options[0].value">
                </radio-button>
            </div>

            </section>
            <h3>Selected value = {{selectedOption}} </h3>
            `,
})

export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

    exampleForm = this.fb.group({
        gender: ['', []],
    });

    selectedOption: string;

    options: Array<{ value: string, display: string }> = [
        { value: 'Male', display: 'Male' },
        { value: 'Female', display: 'Female' }
    ];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.selectedOptionChange(this.options[0].value);
    }

    selectedOptionChange(value: any): void {
        this.selectedOption = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably also need to ask for your formGroup as an Input

```
 @Input() group: FormGroup;
```

and also you need an element that acts as container where you add the directive

```
[formGroup]
```

check the edit of your code I made

```
    import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'radio-button',
  //You will also need a DOM element to act as a container of your formControl
  template: `
    <div [formGroup]="group">
        <input type="radio"
            (change)="changeValue(value)"
            class="input-control"
            [id]="inputId"
            [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"
            [value]="value"
            [formControlName]="inputName"/>

        <label
            for="{{ inputId }}">
            <span>{{ label | translate }}</span>
        </label>
        </div>
    `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => RadioComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  styleUrls: ['./radio.less']
})

export class RadioComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() selectedOption: string;
  @Input() inputId: string;
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() inputName: string;
  @Input() group: FormGroup; //You also need to ask for the formgroup 

  @Output() selectedOptionChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  changeValue(value: any) {
    this.selectedOptionChange.emit(value);
  }

  _onChange = (_: any) => { };
  _onTouched = () => { };


  writeValue(value: any): void {
    console.log('writeValue=', value);
    this._onChange(value);
  }


  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => {}): void {
    this._onChange = fn;
  }


  registerOnTouched(fn: () => {}): void {
    this._onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

you could also post a working example so we could better help you. Maybe upload it to https://stackblitz.com

---

EDIT

For completeness sake I´ve also added the part of your demo component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-radio',
    template: `

            <div  [formGroup]="exampleForm">
                <radio-button *ngFor="let option of options"
                    [inputId] = "option.value"
                    [label]="option.display"
                    [value]="option.value"
                    (selectedOptionChange) = "selectedOptionChange($event)"
                    formInputName= "gender"
                    [selectedOption]="options[0].value"
                    [group]="exampleForm"
                    >
                </radio-button>
            </div>

            </section>
            <h3>Selected value = {{selectedOption}} </h3>
            `,
})

export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

    exampleForm = this.fb.group({
        gender: ['', []],
    });

    selectedOption: string;

    options: Array<{ value: string, display: string }> = [
        { value: 'Male', display: 'Male' },
        { value: 'Female', display: 'Female' }
    ];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.selectedOptionChange(this.options[0].value);
    }

    selectedOptionChange(value: any): void {
        this.selectedOption = value;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: proof of concept

You can check a proof of concept [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqqkez). It is a barebones version of what you are doing. It only has 3 components. The app-component, and two more similar to what you are doing.

Comment: adding formGroup to RadioComponent will create multiple element with formgroup, means I can check both the options "Male" and "Female". only way would be i move ngFor inside the radio component which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @Vin05 I´m not sure about that, but I´ve used that same schema to split forms across tab components, where i use a single formGroup that I pass as reference of my formGroup to the child components. Tough I do not use the UseExisting bits

Comment: @Vino5 If what you´re talking about the DIV then you culd use an NG-CONTAINER instead, so that there are no new DOM elements added. See reference [here](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)

Comment: hello @Omar i uploaded my example to stackBlitz can you please help a look? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mipzzw I comment the formControlName line as with that its not displaying any thing.

Comment: @Vin05 check the changes I made on my [fork of your app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w5sjh7). I commented where I added or deleted things

Comment: Also, I think the part where you are trying to emit the chages is messing up the rest of your form. Also the part of how you try to setup an initial value